# Fixing intersecting tuples for good

Tags: typescript, types

This problem is popping up more and more in my generic code in a variety of situations and I am sick writing ad hoc utility types for each situation:

The tuple spread syntax is broken when a tuple has been intersected with an array.

```js
type A = number[] & [1, 2];
type B = [...A] // (1 | 2)[]
```

They are also similarily fragile when you try to map over them in some situations.

I would like to find a way to get to the tuple in a general way.

I suppose that getting the array is not as important because it is wider than the tuple in my use cases, but theoretically it could be narrower as well.

My first attempt which yields the correct result requires a `Hint` parameter. I would really like to get rid of it but I can't get TS to infer the correct types when using `any[]` or `unknown[]`

```js
type SplitArrayTuple<Arr extends readonly unknown[], Hint> =
    Arr extends Hint[] & infer T
        ? Arr extends T & infer A
            ? {arr: A, tuple: T}
        : never
    : never

type  Tup = ['foo'?, ...('bar'|'quux')[]];

type Foo = SplitArrayTuple<string[] & Tup, string>
type Bar = SplitArrayTuple<'quux'[] & Tup, 'quux'>
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UCuA7A1ig9gdxQbQF0oAyKPARgBooAmAgbgChRIoAhBMgOh5iIHp+UABTkoAH1oBKQo2bhoAZTAAbAJbAYAJy0BDEABUkqiAB5tWqBAAewCCgAmAZyhaIuh5hQqQydFlxCagAJNRRgAD4ERihY2B0rW3tnKFDwwhIoMIAzCEsDGLiigH54yxs7RxcDTJy82EKipqhSgG9dHQAuWGpgYxUIboMAX0am7pQIADc8sYnp2flWKCMwTjwAcmzMTA3i6h4uYQ2AIw6N8Q2ARyQkaw2ZAgY5FmgAMR3OZXVNHX1VgamJzALRhADmGVIq2owNBKDBESW0DYHS+qg0Fn+-TM11u90hK2M1Fxdw2ESAA)

I was thinking about recursively reconstructing the tuple but there are a few edge cases to consider, like optional elements and open-ended tuples. It's not possible to rely on the tuple length and I can see aliasing problems coming up. It's also only going to give me values which are already the result of the intersection, but this actually may be fine.

Can you think of alternate designs or of a way to get me unstuck with the implementation above?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I made some progress.

`FixTuple` works by decomposing a tuple into its constituents (is it readonly, does it have optional elements, what is its index signature, what is it's length), and reconstructing it from scratch.

```js
type FixTuple<T> = Recompose<Decompose<T>>;

type Decompose<T> = {
    isReadonly: T extends unknown[] ? never : unknown,
    length: number,
    index: { [K in keyof T as K extends number ? K : never]: T[K] }[any],
    optional: OptionalIndices<T>
} & {
    [K in keyof T as K extends `${number}` | 'length' ? K : never]: T[K]
}

type OptionalIndices<T> = {
    [K in keyof T as {} extends { [P in K]: T[P]; } ? K : never]-?: K extends `${infer N extends number}` ? N : never
} extends infer U ? U[keyof U] : never

type Decomposed =  {
    length: number,
    index: unknown,
    isReadonly: unknown,
    optional: unknown
}

type Recompose<
    T extends Decomposed,
    I extends number = 0,
    R extends unknown[] = [],
    Values = never
> = T extends { [K in I]?: unknown }
    ? Recompose<
        T,
        Next<I>,
        I extends T['optional'] ? [...R, T[I]?] : [...R, T[I]],
        Values | T[I]
    >
    : HandleReadonly<T, HandleOpenEnded<T, R, Values>>

type HandleOpenEnded<T extends Decomposed, R extends unknown[], Values> =
    number extends T['length']
    ? [...R, ...Exclude<T['index'], Values>[]]
    : R;

type HandleReadonly<T extends Decomposed, R extends unknown[]> =
    [T['isReadonly']] extends [never] ? R : readonly [...R]


type Next<I extends number> =
    number extends I ? number
    : number & [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64][I];
```

It works in every use case I found except when the array the original tuple was intersected with is not wider than it, but this issue is probably due to a bug:

```js
(string[] & [1, 2, 3]) extends string[] ? true : false // true instead of false
```

```js
(string[] & [1, 2, 3])[1] // 2 instead of never
```

For reference, `string[] & number[]` is `never[]` so there is definitely an inconsistency here. I'll file an issue.